# Pulling multiple data sets from JSON

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

The basic set up is a simple JSON file which I am pulling into a page via ajax. Now I've got it working fine with this code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            var tour = $('.js-featureTour');
            $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "tour.json",
                    dataTyple: "json",
                    success: function (result) {
                        var imgSrc = result.image;
                        $('.js-featureTourTitle').text(result.tourTitle);
                        $('.js-featureTourDesc').html(result.tourDesc);
                        $('.js-featureTourImg').attr('src', imgSrc);
                    }
                })
            });
```

This worked well with my test JSON file but what I actually have to work with is something like this

```
{
    "tour1": {
        "tourTitle": "Test Title 1",
        "tourDesc": "description 1",
        "image": "/main1.jpg"
    },
    "tour2": {
        "tourTitle": "Test Title 2",
        "tourDesc": "description 2",
        "image": "/main2.jpg"
    },
    "tour3": {
        "tourTitle": "Test Title 3",
        "tourDesc": "description 3",
        "image": "/main3.jpg"
    }
}
```

What I really want is for the success stage to read what is in "tour1" insert it into the page, then wait for a bit then read what is in "tour2" and over write the "tour1" information and then do the same for "tour3". Can anyone help me out here? I've been stuck on this for longer than I care to admit. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop through the Json Object and use `SetTimeout` to delay the manipulation of data in DOM. Try try below code.

```
success: function (result) {
    $.each(results, function(i,result) {
        setInterval(function(){
          var imgSrc = result.image;
          $('.js-featureTourTitle').text(result.tourTitle);
          $('.js-featureTourDesc').html(result.tourDesc);
          $('.js-featureTourImg').attr('src', imgSrc);
        },5000)
    })
}
```

Comment: Hey! thanks for the response. This kinda works but it doesn't display tour1 and tour2 but instead waits 5 seconds then displays tour3

Comment: Try using above code. i have modified it by using $.each instead foreach

Comment: Thanks again, I'm still getting the same result though :(. this is my first jump into ajax/JSON so apologies for being a noob

Comment: sorry dude. we need to use setInterval instead of setTimeOut.

Comment: Looks like its getting closer. I really hate to be a pain in the ass but on my end I'm still getting nothing for 5 seconds then what looks like a jump through all the results ending at tour3

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `setInterval`:

```
function handleTours(json) { //call this from the callback
    var elements = []; //build a set of elements which will help
    for (key in json) {
        elements.push(key: key, structure: json[key]);
    }
    if (elements.length > 0) { //if there are no elements, do nothing
        var index = 0;
        var intervalID = setInterval(function() { //we store intervalID to stop the repetition when we are at the end of the set
            if (index >= elements.length) {
                clearInterval(intervalID); //we are at the end of the set
            } else {
                //do something with elements[index].key and elements[index].structure
                index++;
            }
        }, 5000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record I got it working with this

```
success: function (result) {
                    var time = 0;
                    $.each(result, function(i, result) {
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            var imgSrc = result.image;
                            $('.js-featureTourTitle').text(result.tourTitle);
                            $('.js-featureTourDesc').html(result.tourDesc);
                            $('.js-featureTourImg').attr('src', imgSrc);
                            },time)
                            time += 5000;
                        })
                    }
```

Thanks for the help!